# Waterfall Stacked BarChart

Tags: charts

Trying to make a waterfall bar chart.  I got this far:

```
yData = {10, 7, 4, 2}
upFromX = Accumulate[yData] - yData
xyDataWithUplift = 
 Table[{Style[upFromX[[i]], White], yData[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[yData]}]
BarChart[xyDataWithUplift, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

which is getting there but I can't figure out how to make the bottom rectangle's edge blank.  Tried `EdgeForm[]` and `EdgeForm[White]` but no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this?

```
yData = {10, 7, 4, 2, -5, -2, 3};
    BarChart[yData, ChartLayout -> "Stepped"]
```

[image]

Comment: thx - that's so obvious it never occurred to me... now that I see it, that's exactly how a 'stepped' layout should behave1

Answer (score 1):

```
yData = {10, 7, 4, 10, -5, -2, 4};
```

To visualize step directions, we can use `ChartLayout -> "Stepped"` with built-in `ChartElementFunction`s as follows:

#### "FadingRectangle"

```
BarChart[yData, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stepped", 
 ChartStyle -> Red, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementData["FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin" -> Bottom]]
```

[image]

#### "GradientRectangle"`

```
BarChart[yData, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stepped", 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 ChartElementFunction ->  ChartElementData["GradientRectangle", 
   "ColorScheme" -> {Red, Orange, White},
   "GradientOrigin" -> Bottom]]
```

[image]

#### "ArrowRectangle"

```
BarChart[yData, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stepped", 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 ChartElementFunction -> "ArrowRectangle"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use both `ChartElementFunction` and `ColorFunction`:

```
BarChart[yData, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stepped",
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementData["ArrowRectangle", "ArrowWidth" -> .8, 
   "TaperRatio" -> 0, "ArrowheadAngle" -> 120]]
```

[image]

**Note:** We can access the options for a built-in `ChartElementFunction` using `"Options"` as the second argument:

```
ChartElementData["ArrowRectangle", "Options"]
```

> ```
> {"TaperRatio" -> 0, "ArrowheadAngle" -> 60, "ArrowWidth" -> 0.6}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I expected `ChartStyle -> {{None, Automatic}}` to work but it still had the edge.

`ChartStyle -> {{Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[]], Automatic}}` on the other hand does remove the edge.